# HTML Content after table disappears

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I´m making a webshop with woocommerce.

At every product I want to add a table with information of the product, like color, delivery time and some more.

But when I add this table. All content after this product disappears.

The code for my table:

```css
td {    
border: 1px solid black;
}
table {
border: 6px solid #C6A970;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
td {
padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>Color:</td><td>White</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Size:</td><td>100-110 x 60-70</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Delivery time:</td><td>2-3 working days</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

What am I doing wrong in this code that my content disappears?

Comment: As far as i know you dont need to create this table by coding. The woocommerce plugin has the option to add custom attributes to your product everytime you add a new one. Try to explore the plugin a little bit more my advice.

Comment: Can you provide me a link to that? I can't find anything that looks like a table. And that's not my biggest problem. My problem is that at certain points, my content disappears. If I delete this code, everything works fine as before.

Comment: Here is the documentation of woocommerce for this task https://docs.woothemes.com/document/variable-product/

Comment: Thanx for the link. I'll have a look at it ;)

Comment: dont forget to vote up if it helps :)

Comment: I looked at your link, but than I get a new tab with extra info. That's not what I want. I want it above the price button. So I used the text block for it, but than at the last of my category, everything disappears. Error from wordpress?

Comment: The best and easy way would be to display it in a widget. But after that you can edit the woocommerce templates. you can find how to do that on woocommerce docs.

Comment: I fixed my problem. I have put the description under my product name on the product page, so if that content is too big, the rest of my page content disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
td {    
border: 1px solid black;
}
table {
border: 6px solid #C6A970;
margin-bottom: 10px;
clear:both;
}
td {
padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>Color:</td><td>White</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Size:</td><td>100-110 x 60-70</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Delivery time:</td><td>2-3 working days</td>
</tr>
</table>
```